# Different portions of JSON.stringify(new Date());

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

> 2014-07-29T16:55:46.657Z

I believe it to be:

YEAR-MONTH-DAY`T`HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS.MILLISECONDS`Z`

What is the purpose and full name of `T` and `Z`?

Do they just serve as escape characters?

Comment: Full names: "Time" and "Zulu" ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario really `Z`=Zulu?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario "UTC time is also known as 'Zulu' time, since 'Zulu' is the NATO phonetic alphabet word for 'Z'."  Wow, I didn't believe it.

Comment: @onepiece: Yup. That's a standard way to say UTC/GMT, because the `Z` indicator means UTC and `Z` in the NATO phonetic alphabet is "Zulu". *Edit* Ah, I see you got there yourself. :-)

Comment: What I didn't know is why Z in the first place. [I've just googled that](http://www.maybeck.com/ztime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` separates date and time; `Z` specifies a UTC timezone. (In place of it, `-08:00` can appear, for example.)

Comment: @Jeroen Noten: Note that JavaScript's date/time string format [is not ISO-8601](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2014/07/javascripts-datetime-format-is-not-iso.html). It's a subset of 8601 with a fairly critical incompatibility around what it means if you don't include a timezone indicator on the string.

Answer (score 1):

JSON has no notion of dates, and so if you do `JSON.stringify(new Date())`, you're in effect doing `JSON.stringify(new Date().toJSON())` ([link to spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.44)), which gives the date using JavaScript's date/time format. You can get all the gory details about that format in [§15.9.1.15](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) of the spec.

JavaScript's [pseudo-ISO-8601 date/time format](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2014/07/javascripts-datetime-format-is-not-iso.html) uses `T` as the separator between dates and times, and `Z` as the indicator of UTC (sometimes called GMT). In JavaScript, *without* the `Z`, that would still be in UTC (whereas in ISO-8601, it would be "local time"). Instead of the `Z`, you can specify a timezone offset.

Comment: `In JavaScript, without the Z, that would still be in UTC (whereas in ISO-8601, it would be "local time").`  Aren't UTC (actual time outputted by JavaScript) and local time the same?  For example, the `16:55:46.657Z` in my question is UTC since it has the `Z`, but it's also my local time.

Comment: @onepiece: UTC is only local time in a very few places right now, some west African states like Gambia. Nearly everyone else who uses GMT the rest of the year is on GMT+0100 (daylight saving time) right now. But leaving that aside, other than people in the fairly narrow band on either side of the line passing through Greenwich (the UK, Portugal, and those African states), the vast majority of people on the planet have a local time that is offset from UTC all year. In New York (Eastern Daylight Time), the time is UTC-0500 or UTC-0400 (in summer); in New Delhi, it's (always) UTC+0530.